# How to use python console in Pycharm using Docker for Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, docker-compose, pycharm, docker-for-mac

When I run a docker-compose app in pycharm with docker compose I can't connect to python console. All the configs seems to be good. Pycharm scan the interpreter with all the requirements.  But when I open `python console` I get an error:

```
    018, 21:07:40) 
  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 303, in run
    self._on_run()
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 1521, in _on_run
    self.send_result(xml)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 1543, in send_result
    self.frame_accessor.ReturnFullValue(self.seq, xml.getvalue())
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in single_request
    http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1279, in send_request
    self.send_content(connection, request_body)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1309, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
  socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Assuming the server you want to connect to called `web`, have you tried `docker-compose exec web python` in the terminal? you should be able to connect to the python console inside the web container

Comment: @NourChawich yes, I can connect to python through docker command. The problem is a connection through `Pycharm python console`. I made it on the linux machine, but I can't do it on the macos.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue was fixed. Pycharm can connect to the docker-compose interpreter through python console

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on macbook m1, try to change your docker-compose file with this params and then choose your_service in Pycharm interpreter settings:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    your_service:
    platform:
      linux/amd64
    image: gitlab-registry/your_service:master
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
        - your_service.lan
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```